# Google Charts Loading Error

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I recently ran into a strange issue with Google Charts and loading Google web fonts asynchronously. I was using `loader.js` and loading the most current version of the charts via `google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });`. Specifically, I was trying to draw two line charts on the same page and at the same time and set their attributes as below:

```
var options = {
   ...,
   ...,
   titleTextStyle: {
      ...,
      fontName: 'Lato'
   }
}
```

I then set some additional attributes and defined the data and proceeded to draw the charts like normal. The first chart would be drawn but the second one would never materialize. Nothing was working so I backtracked through the code deleting chunks until I found that deleting `fontName: 'Lato'` is what resolved the issue. I was asynchronously loading my web fonts with this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
WebFontConfig = {
    google: {
        families: ['Lato:300, 400, 900']
    }
};
(function() {
    var wf = document.createElement('script');
    wf.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') +
        '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.6.26/webfont.js';
    wf.type = 'text/javascript';
    wf.async = 'true';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
})();
</script>
```

Loading my fonts while using this script, I was able to draw one chart, but when I attempted to draw two charts, I was never able to complete it. Every time, the first chart would be populated and the second chart never loaded. I had defined Lato as my primary font, but I did have backups defined as well. This didn't seem to help. My final solution was to load the web font the standard way with:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,900" rel="stylesheet">
```

This resolved the issue but I don't like the idea of not being able to load the font asynchronously. Has anyone run into this awkward issue before or am I just missing something really obvious?

*****EDIT*****
Full chart code attached:

```
google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var fontSizeGraph = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('graph_font_size_source'), null).getPropertyValue('font-size');
    fontSizeGraph = parseFloat(fontSizeGraph);
    var interactivityPermissive = true;
    if ($(window).width() < 768) {
        interactivityPermissive = false;
    } else {
        interactivityPermissive = true;
    };
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Accepted Variance', 'High/Low', 'HiHi/LoLo'],
        ['0', 0, 0],
        ['1', 38, 45],
        ['2', 60, 68],
        ['3', 67, 75],
        ['4', 76, 88],
        ['5', 80, 93],
        ['6', 90, 102],
        ['7', 98, 108],
        ['8', 100, 111],
        ['9', 105, 117],
        ['10', 111, 123],
        ['11', 114, 126],
        ['12', 118, 130],
        ['13', 120, 134],
        ['14', 124, 140],
        ['15', 127, 142],
        ['16', 130, 145],
        ['16', 131, 146],
        ['18', 134, 148],
        ['19', 137, 153],
        ['20', 138, 155]
    ]);
    var options = {
        enableInteractivity: interactivityPermissive,
        title: 'Delay Tags Preserved',
        titlePosition: 'out',
        titleTextStyle: {
            color: '#3D414D',
            fontName: "Lato",
            fontSize: fontSizeGraph,
            bold: true
        },
        chartArea: {
            //top: '7%',
            width: '90%',
            height: '70%'
        },
        //chartArea: {'top': 0, 'left': 0},
        colors: ['#3D414D', '#4EDEC2'],
        curveType: 'function',
        fontName: "Lato",
        legend: {
            position: 'bottom',
            textStyle: {
                color: '#3D414D',
                fontName: "Lato"
            }
        },
        vAxis: {
            title: 'Alarm Count Reduction',
            viewWindow: {
                max: 180,
                min: -5,
                format: '#',
            },
            textStyle: {
                color: '#3D414D',
                fontName: "Lato"
            },
            showTextEvery: 20,
            textPosition: 'in',
            gridlines: {
                color: '#EFECE7',
                count: 5
            }
        },
        hAxis: {
            title: 'Accepted Variance (%)',
            titleTextStyle: {
                color: '#3D414D',
                fontName: "Lato"
            },
            viewWindow: {
                max: 24,
                min: 0,
            },
            textStyle: {
                color: '#3D414D',
                fontName: "Lato"
            },
            format: '#',
            showTextEvery: 2,
            viewWindowMode: 'maximized'
        },
        lineWidth: 2,
        tooltip: {
            textStyle: {
                color: '#3D414D',
                fontName: "Lato",
                fontSize: (fontSizeGraph * 0.5)
            },
            //isHtml: true,
            ignoreBounds: true
        },
        animation: {
            duration: 1000,
            startup: true,
            easing: 'out'
        }
    };

    var chart1 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('results_graph_1'));
    chart1.draw(data, options);

    var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Accepted Variance', 'High/Low', 'HiHi/LoLo'],
        ['0', 0, 0],
        ['1', 81, 88],
        ['2', 135, 142],
        ['3', 180, 189],
        ['4', 223, 237],
        ['5', 255, 270],
        ['6', 303, 317],
        ['7', 343, 354],
        ['8', 362, 373],
        ['9', 380, 392],
        ['10', 406, 419],
        ['11', 420, 432],
        ['12', 443, 456],
        ['13', 459, 473],
        ['14', 476, 493],
        ['15', 493, 510],
        ['16', 513, 530],
        ['16', 520, 537],
        ['18', 533, 548],
        ['19', 546, 563],
        ['20', 555, 572]
    ]);

    var options = {
        enableInteractivity: interactivityPermissive,
        title: 'Delay Tags Modified',
        titlePosition: 'out',
        titleTextStyle: {
            color: '#3D414D',
            fontName: "Lato",
            fontSize: fontSizeGraph,
            bold: true
        },
        chartArea: {
            //top: '7%',
            width: '90%',
            height: '70%'
        },
        //chartArea: {'top': 0, 'left': 0},
        colors: ['#3D414D', '#4EDEC2'],
        curveType: 'function',
        fontName: "Lato",
        legend: {
            position: 'bottom',
            textStyle: {
                color: '#3D414D',
                fontName: "Lato"
            }
        },
        vAxis: {
            title: 'Alarm Count Reduction',
            viewWindow: {
                max: 600,
                min: -5,
                format: '#',
            },
            textStyle: {
                color: '#3D414D',
                fontName: "Lato"
            },
            showTextEvery: 20,
            textPosition: 'in',
            gridlines: {
                color: '#EFECE7',
                count: 5
            }
        },
        hAxis: {
            title: 'Accepted Variance (%)',
            titleTextStyle: {
                color: '#3D414D',
                fontName: "Lato"
            },
            viewWindow: {
                max: 24,
                min: 0,
            },
            textStyle: {
                color: '#3D414D',
                fontName: "Lato"
            },
            format: '#',
            showTextEvery: 2,
            viewWindowMode: 'maximized'
        },
        lineWidth: 2,
        tooltip: {
            textStyle: {
                color: '#3D414D',
                fontName: "Lato",
                fontSize: (fontSizeGraph * 0.5)
            },
            //isHtml: true,
            ignoreBounds: true
        },
        animation: {
            duration: 1000,
            startup: true,
            easing: 'out'
        }
    };

    var chart2 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('results_graph_2'));
    chart2.draw(data2, options);
}
```

Comment: would be helpful to see the chart code as well...

Comment: Full code has now been appended to original post.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, having 4 charts on one page, together with async webfont loader. Some charts randomly did not display.

It seems that, if there is a font specified on chart options, on draw, code checks if there is `window.WebFont` object, if yes, use it to load the font(s). Even if this font(s) is already loaded by webfont loader. Each chart draw call, keeps requesting the same fonts, and they keep getting appended as `<link>`s in `<head>`. This seems buggy behavior.
The way i hack fixed it, is removing webfont object before calling first chart draw.

```
google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'], 'callback': {
    window.WebFont = null;
    var chart1 = someChart();
    chart1.draw();
}});
```